# jpa + hibernate Query for get records from two tables with join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to get record like :-

```
toolTypeId, quantity, toolName , onTruck, Damage, loss
    2         50        test1      20      25      5
```

**onTruck, Damage, loss**:- total records from list

first 3 are from toolsType table and last 3 from userTools.

My model classes :-

**ToolsType.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String toolName;
private Long quantity;
```

**UserTools.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private ToolsType toolsType;
private Long loss;
private Long onTruck;
private Long damage;
```

I am trying something like that in my Repository file 
:- `select count(toolstype.id), toolstype.toolName, quantity FROM toolstype GROUP BY(toolstype.id);`

I know its not correct Please help me for correct query for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this query. Hope it will help you. You need to use `alias` in this case.

```
select count(ttype.id), ttype.toolName, ttype.quantity FROM toolstype as ttype GROUP BY(ttype.id);
```

UPDATED Query is given below:

```
select count(ttype.id), ttype.toolName, ttype.quantity, utools.onTruck, utools.damage, utools.loss
FROM toolstype ttype, usertools utools 
where ttype.id = utools.id
GROUP BY ttype.toolName, ttype.quantity, utools.onTruck, utools.damage, utools.loss
```

Comment: #sky Thanks for your Comment,  It return only one table data, But according to my question i need 2 tables data. Can you please check my question again i just update it.

Comment: With UPDATED Query, It return wrong Output, It return [1, Tool One, 50, 65, 3, 2]

Comment: [count, toolName, quantity] this is correct but after that it return only first row record, i need sum of onTruck, damage, loss where ttype.id is same

Answer (score 0):

You must use this JPQL query:

```
select tt.id, count(tt.id), tt.toolname, ut.onTruck, ut.damage, ut.loss
from UserTools ut
join ut.toolsType tt
group by tt.id, tt.toolname, ut.onTruck, ut.damage, ut.loss
```

You need to put all `select` values in the `group by` clause for the query to group the results.

UPDATE:

If you need the sum of `UserTools` values and all the `ToolsType` values in the result, the query would be:

```
select tt.id, count(tt.id), tt.toolname, sum(ut.onTruck), sum(ut.damage), sum(ut.loss)
from ToolsType tt, UserTools ut
where tt.id = ut.toolsType.id
group by tt.id, tt.toolname, ut.onTruck, ut.damage, ut.loss
```

I also think that the relation between `UserTools` and `ToolType` would be `@ManyToOne` instead of `@OneToOne`.

Comment: #JMS Thanks for your replay, but its not return correct result i am not getting all records of ToolsType table

Comment: I need somthing like that select  * from toolsType and (join) select from UserTools where toolsType = same and sum all damage, sum all onTruck, sum all loss